Issue runing a background image changing script with crontab on reboot
Im trying to create a script to change the background image on startup.
I created a file with this code:
REAL_UID=$(id --real --user)
PID=$(pgrep --euid $REAL_UID gnome-session | head -n 1)
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=$(grep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /proc/$PID/environ|cut -d= -f2- | sed -e "s/\x0//g")

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri-dark file:///Path_to_jpg
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:///Path_to_jpg

When i try to run this file with a cron configuration to run every minute like this, i dont have an issue:
*/1 * * * * /home/alejandro/Wallpaper.sh

But when i configure it like this, it doesnt work:
@reboot /home/alejandro/Wallpaper.sh

I added a line with "date >> /file" to check if the script was running and it does write a log.
What is missing for the script to work on startup?

most probably because at reboot when the cron activates no GUI or Gnome session has started yet. add echo "PID is $PID " >> file to see if you get the right PID at reboot. then update your question.

Similarly check DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS is correct when cron executes your script at reboot.

You are right, PID is null when the script runs on reboot. Then what can i do for this to work? I had this before in version 23 but i forgot what i did ;(

You may want to run your script automatically after you login using the  Startup Applications.  This ensures there is a GUI and you are actually logged in when the script runs.
